# unordered_multiset pointer in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Iam beginner in C++, and I want to use insert function of `unordered multiset` pointer below to add new element:

```
struct Customer {
 size_t operator()(const char& c) const;
};

unordered_multiset<char, Customer>* ms
```

can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

```
void populate_multiset(const string& s, unordered_multiset<char, CustomHasher>* ms)
```

Given this function accepts a `string` and your `unordered_multiset` accepts a `char`, You can only insert a `char`

```
for(size_t i = 0; i<s.size(); i++) {
    ms->insert(s[i]); // insert each individual char
}
```

Or use the iterators to insert a range of `char`

```
ms->insert(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Also, since the standard library already provides a way to hash a `char`. You can simply declare

```
unordered_multiset<char> ms;
```

However, if you do want to provide a custom hash function, you can. And the syntax is exactly like what you have in your question.

And a far more common way to pass in a container to a function is through reference. e.g.

```
void populate_multiset(const string& s, unordered_multiset<char, CustomHasher>& ms)
```

Then, you can use `.` instead of `->` to do the exact same thing.